imagedata[] diplay in OnPaint() with MFC
OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this);
  CDC memDC;
  memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
  memDC.Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
  dc.BitBlt(0,0,100,100,&memDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
}

no display anything..
OnPaint()
{
  CBitmap bmp;
  bmp.createBitmap(24,24,1,24,img);
  CBitmap* oldBitmap = memDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
  dc.BitBlt(0,0,24,24,&memDC, 0,0,SRCCOPY);
}

trying this.. no display.
the img[..] has pixel data, which is generated from another func().
OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this);
  dc.rectangle(0,0,100,100);
}

but it works..
the img[..] was generated by this code
for (auto i=0;i<w*h*3;i+=3)
{
   img[i] = m_Image[n][i];  // R
   img[i+1] = m_Image[n][i+1]; // G
   img[i+2] = m_Image[n][i+2]; // B
}


You render an image by selecting it into a memory device context and performing a BitBlt()/StretchBlt() to the destination device context. Selecting an object into a device context doesn't perform any rendering by itself.

I already try to. 'dc.BitBlt(.., &dc,0,0,SRCCOPY)'... and 'memDC.selectobject(&bmp); dc.BitBlt(..,&memDC,..); '  .. but it doesnot display..

We cannot help if you aren't showing your code. Please show a [mcve] and read through [ask].

the img was generated by this code
